# Passing URL parameter and a form data together

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have following URL:

http://localhost:49970/Messages/Index/9999

And at view "Index" I have a form and I post the form data to the action Index (decored with [HttpPost]) using Jquery, like this:

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMessages() {
        var URL = "Index";
        $.post(
            URL,
            $("form").serialize(),
             function(data) {
                 $('#tabela').html(data);
             }
        );
    }
</script>

 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <%=Html.TextArea("Message") %>

        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send" onclick="javascript:getMessages();" />

    <% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
   //do something...
     return PartialView("SomePartialView", someModel);
}
```

My question: How can I get the parameter "9999" and the form FormCollection in the action Index?

PS: Sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the id in the routes collection. Then, just put a verible with the same name in the action.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string otherPostData...)
{
   //do something...
     return PartialView("SomePartialView", someModel);
}
```

Look here for the details how MVC url routing works:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Mendy :)

Actually, my parameter is a guid (something like "08254a2a-7089-46e6-b03d-406a72a34148"). I try to declared the method like did you say:

public ActionResult Index(Guid? id, string Message)
{
   //id is null
   //Message is ok (has the value that I typed)
     return PartialView("SomePartialView", someModel);
}

If I change the nullable Guid? to only Guid, when I clck in the button nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add the `Id` to your form values.

This should do the trick:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <%=Html.Hidden("Id") %>

    <%=Html.TextArea("Message") %>

    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send" onclick="javascript:getMessages();" />

<% } %>
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to throw the `Id` into your `ViewData` in the controller.

Another way to do it (which could be cleaner) would be to get the `URL` that jQuery posts to from the form's action attribute. While you're at it I'd make the js unobtrusive too.

HTHs,
Charles